# Elasticsearch bucket_script returns no output

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I created an index like that:

```json
{
   "mappings":{
      "properties":{
         "@timestamp":{
            "type":"date",
            "doc_values":true
         },
         "event.category":{
            "type":"keyword",
            "index":true
         },
         "action":{
            "type":"keyword",
            "index":true
         },
         "success":{
            "type":"boolean",
            "index":true
         },
         "raw":{
            "type":"text",
            "index":false
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Then I tried to use `bucket_script` pipeline aggregation to calculate success rate over actions, searching like that

```json
    {
        "size": 0,
        "_source": false,
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "filter": [{
                        "term": {
                            "action": "login"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "aggs": {
            "action_bucket": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "action",
                    "show_term_doc_count_error": true
                },
                "aggs": {
                    "total": {
                        "terms": {
                            "field": "action"
                        }
                    },
                    "action": {
                        "filter": {
                            "term": {
                                "success": true
                            }
                        },
                        "aggs": {
                            "success": {
                                "terms": {
                                    "field": "action"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "action_success_rate": {
                        "bucket_script": {
                            "buckets_path": {
                                "no_total": "total.doc_count",
                                "no_success": "action>success.doc_count"
                            },
                            "script": "100 * params.no_success / params.no_total"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And inside the response there is not `action_success_rate`:

```json
    {
        "took": 3,
        "timed_out": false,
        "_shards": {
            "total": 1,
            "successful": 1,
            "skipped": 0,
            "failed": 0
        },
        "hits": {
            "total": {
                "value": 15,
                "relation": "eq"
            },
            "max_score": null,
            "hits": []
        },
        "aggregations": {
            "action_bucket": {
                "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                "buckets": [
                    {
                        "key": "login",
                        "doc_count": 15,
                        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                        "total": {
                            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                            "buckets": [
                                {
                                    "key": "login",
                                    "doc_count": 15
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "action": {
                            "doc_count": 9,
                            "success": {
                                "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                                "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                                "buckets": [
                                    {
                                        "key": "login",
                                        "doc_count": 9
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

How could I fix my search request body to obtain success rate?

Answer (score 0):

**Mapping:**

```
{
   "mappings":{
      "properties":{
         "@timestamp":{
            "type":"date",
            "doc_values":true
         },
         "event.category":{
            "type":"keyword",
            "index":true
         },
         "action":{
            "type":"keyword",
            "index":true
         },
         "success":{
            "type":"boolean",
            "index":true
         },
         "raw":{
            "type":"text",
            "index":false
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**Sample Data:**

```
    {
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 5,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "idx0",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "E802dnkBHcKLV4rtwh3V",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "action" : "login",
          "success" : true
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "idx0",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "FM02dnkBHcKLV4rtyx0r",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "action" : "login",
          "success" : true
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "idx0",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Fc02dnkBHcKLV4rt1x0t",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "action" : "login",
          "success" : false
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "idx0",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Fs04dnkBHcKLV4rtKR3P",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "action" : "logout",
          "success" : false
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "idx0",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "F804dnkBHcKLV4rtNR3J",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "action" : "logout",
          "success" : true
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Query:**

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "actions": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "action.keyword",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "total": {
          "value_count": {
            "field": "action.keyword"
          }
        },
        "success":{
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "success":true
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "success_cnt": {
              "value_count": {
                "field": "action.keyword"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "success_rate":{
          "bucket_script": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "no_total":"total.value",
              "no_success":"success>success_cnt.value"
            },
            "script": "(params.no_success/params.no_total)*100"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Response:**

```
{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 5,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "actions" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "login",
          "doc_count" : 3,
          "total" : {
            "value" : 3
          },
          "success" : {
            "doc_count" : 2,
            "success_cnt" : {
              "value" : 2
            }
          },
          "success_rate" : {
            "value" : 66.66666666666666
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "logout",
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "total" : {
            "value" : 2
          },
          "success" : {
            "doc_count" : 1,
            "success_cnt" : {
              "value" : 1
            }
          },
          "success_rate" : {
            "value" : 50.0
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: ```json
{
    "took": 9,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 31,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "actions": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": []
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I created the similar mapping and tried it out before posting the query .. it was working well for me ... I updated the mapping, data, query and response as well